# Matlab summation to form matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, sum

I am looking for some help with a fast loop to form a bunch of values. Given a 30-vector, **x** and another 30-vector which is the expected value of such data **expx**. I want to be able to quickly sum 30*30=90 values to form a symmetric 30x30 matrix. Here is how the (k,l)-entry of my 30x30 matrix is:

[image]

so **x** forms the entries on the left part of the bracket, x_i and **expx** is the right part, i.e. < x_i > for i=1,2,...,30. You don't need to worry about what values makes up these vectors, I've already determined them. Does anyone know how I should form such elements of the matrix and put them into my 30x30 matrix.

I guess I'd start off with:

```
M=30;
C = zeros(M);
```

I'm struggling to get the summation though.

Comment: That's just an autocorrelation matrix, right?  Have you tried the built-in functions?

Comment: Well I've been calling it 'autocovariance' matrix, I think autocorrelation matrices are different unless I am incorrect? I did use the 'autocorr' and 'toeplitz' function in the past but that only works on a given vector, here I have data from two vectors namely, x and expx, this is of course assuming autocorrelation is the same as autocovariance.

Comment: I believe they are different things actually, because the diagonal entries are 1 indicating the correlation on asset to itself is 1. Auto-covariance have covariances on the diagonal entry which aren't always 1.

Comment: Your diagonal entries aren't 1 (barring something in the calculation of expx that ensures this).  Yeah, maybe autocovariance is a better name.  Just a scale factor difference.

Comment: Also, you have only one vector, the error vector, which is `e(t) = x(t) - expx(t)`

Comment: Sorry, I meant that using the autocorrelation function gives diagonal entries of 1 which is incorrect, hence why I am not using it? 

Surely we can't just subtract the two vectors because of the nature of the summation and the answer that we want?

Comment: I mean the error vector is the input to the correlation (or covariance) computation.  You said `toeplitz` wasn't working because you have two input vectors.  Feed it the error vector instead.

Comment: I did that recently and my diagonal entries are still 1 which probably indicate they are wrong (with the error vector).

Answer (score 0):

why not this:

```
M=30;
C = zeros(M);
for k = 1:30
    for l = 1:30
        for i = 1:30
            C(k,l) = (x(k-i+1) - expx(k-i+1)) * (x(l-i+1) - x(l-i+1));
        end
    end
end
```

Comment: lots of invalid indexes being calculated there, e.g. `k-i+1` is invalid when `i>k`.

Comment: As Ben said, I tried this and got '??? Attempted to access x(0); index must be
a positive integer or logical.' For i>k. Is there a way to add such restrictions?

Comment: @user1523500: You can try `for i = 1:min(k,l)`

Comment: @user1523500 have you tried using [circshift](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/circshift.html) to cycle through the vector (the vector (x-expx)). and Sum (x-expx) circshift(x-expx,1)'